# Parse custom XML schema with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xsd

I am getting custom schema data back from an AJAX call and I need to parse it using jQuery. Any idea how to do this?

Here's the XML:

```
<xsd:get_customer_summary_response xmlns:xsd="http://com/acmeco/ovm/cas/xsd">
  <xsd:customer_details>
    <typ:phone_number xmlns:typ="http://com/acmeco/ovm/cas/types">1.555.5553002</typ:phone_number>
    <typ:timezone xsi:nil="true" xmlns:typ="http://com/acmeco/ovm/cas/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <typ:zipcode xmlns:typ="http://com/acmeco/ovm/cas/types">3002</typ:zipcode>
...
  </xsd:customer_details>
</xsd:get_customer_summary_response>
```

And here's the AJAX call. I can parse normal XML with the below, but not XSD stuff.

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "so.xml",

       dataType: "html",

        success: function(returnhtml){ 
    $("customer_details", returnhtml).find("zipcode").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
    }, etc.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but have you tried:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "so.xml",

   dataType: "html",

    success: function(returnhtml){ 
    $(returnhtml).find("customer_details zipcode").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
}, etc.
```

The `context` argument of jQuery expects a DOM element.

`returnhtml` will be an HTML string according to [`jQuery's ajax() documentation`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) if you set the `dataType` as HTML. If it's an XML string, you'd need to have jQuery convert it into an element you can work with first, before using it as context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parseXML` for it.

```
success: function (returnhtml) { 
    var parsedXML = $.parseXML(returnhtml);
    $(parsedXML).find("zipcode").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/jjt894dc/